# How to insert line before any line containing a certain string from vim or command line?

Tags: vim, sed, command-line, grep

I have a file with a bunch of data, for example:

```
something_id: someId
something_version: someVersion
something_log: someLog
```

I want to add a line of text before every line containing `something_log` which says `something_test: example1`

How would I go about this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to insert a line before (see headline) or after (see question) a certain string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Vim, you can use `:help :global` and `:help :put`:

```
:g/something_log/put!='something_test: example1'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the sed command *insert* which is `i`.
The first part with `/something_log/` is a pattern to match.
Then `i` tells it to insert the following text before the matching line.

`sed '/something_log/ i something_test: example1' <file>`

[Documentation for GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed and its `s` command:

```
sed 's/something_log/something_test: example1\n&/' file
```

Output:

```
something_id: someId
something_version: someVersion
something_test: example1
something_log: someLog
```

---

> `&`: repeat the matched part

Answer (score 1):

In `vim` you can go with the `s` command:

```
:%s/something_log/something_test\:example1\rsomething_log/g
```

Assuming `\r` is the new line character.  This line replaces occurences in every line (`%s`) the pattern `something_log` with the new `something_test\:example1\rsomething_log`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for the case you want to paste from default register to line respectively to the matched one. In this example - paste before matched line.

```
:g/str_to_match/-1pu
```